# Bootstrap data-toggle="toggle" checked,unchecked by jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm using bootstrap checkbox with data-toggle="toggle" attribute. I want to set it checked and unchecked with jquery. I tried many ways but it didn't work. Here is my code.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" id="checkbox1">
```

for button click:

```
$("#checkbox").attr('checked',true);
```

**But it's working when I remove `data-toggle="toggle"` attribute.**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Try once with setting property, `$("#checkbox").prop('checked',true);`

Comment: id is ``checkbox1`` but you are using ``checkbox`` in jquery selector

Comment: If you are using **[this](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)**, use `$('#checkbox1').bootstrapToggle('on')`

Comment: Thank you @Mani i missed it. But it's not working

Comment: Thank you @ShaunakD. It's working.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the **[documentation](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)**,

Use

```
$('#checkbox1').bootstrapToggle('on')
```

If you are using `prop()` or `attr()`, there is a workaround,

```
$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true).change()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working if you use id name is correct see the example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" id="checkbox1">Test
 
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkbox1").attr('checked',true);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

**Jquery Code**

```
$('#chk').prop('checked',true);
```

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8uh1u52v/)